# Improper integral outside the domain of the function

Tags: integration

[Improper Integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ahyy.jpg)

[Wolfram Alpha Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSrv4.png)

Obviously improper as the limits run outside the domain of the function. But does it converge? Any machine algorithm I feed this to says it does, and will provide a complex number as the answer. The definition of convergence relies on the limit existing and being finite - which apparently is the case in this instance. But how can I explain that it technically converges when the function isn't even defined on negatives?

Or perhaps ***is*** the function defined on negatives when we include the complex domain? It's kind of freaking me out that I can't get any machine algorithm to tell me this diverges...

Comment: If it makes you feel better, treat $\int\limits_{-1}^2\sqrt{x}~dx$ as $\int\limits_{-1}^0\sqrt{x}~dx~+\int\limits_{0}^2\sqrt{x}~dx$ and recognize that assuming you allow for complex numbers that $\int\limits_{-1}^0 \sqrt{x}~dx = \int\limits_0^1i\cdot\sqrt{x}~dx$.  If you don't allow for complex numbers, then the result will of course be undefined.

Comment: OK JM, thank you -  Will throw an asterisk in there -->Diverges *(unless we allow for complex numbers...)